# Convert custom numeric datevalue to real date in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an application that comes with its own database and there is nothing I can change on that configuration. However we do pull data from the database to generate reports on.

For some reason (which I don't quite grasp), the application stores dates as the following number:

```
numdate = (int) '1' & <last two digits of year> & <zero-leading month> & <zero-leading day>
```

eg:

```
08/10/2008  ->  1081008
01/01/2014  ->  1140101
27/02/2014  ->  1140227
```

For now I just pull in the number and convert it on the go to a real date.

Is it possible to do this conversion via the sql query somehow?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Your examples don't match your definition. Your definition is 1yymmdd but the examples are 1ddmmyy.

Comment: @NikhilButani Microsoft sql server, connection through odbc

Comment: @BernhardHofmann errh, the examples _are_ 1yymmdd, or am I going crazy here?

Comment: @GuntherStruyf You're right - I was confused by the 081008 where the day and year were both 08. (It's still early here for me.) :$

Comment: This is `CYYMMDD`, where the `C` stands for `Century`, and `0` is `1900`  This shows up a lot on older IBM mainframes - before they had `DATE` types (or just to save space) numeric types were used.  The specific type chosen meant you got an odd number of digits, but initially only six were used.  When Y2K became a worry, the official recommendation was simply to store a 1, because it broke the least amount of stuff/required the least amount of work.  Heck, it's safe to use through `2899` - more than enough time to safely switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's SQL Server, the following should work:

```
DECLARE @dateInt INT = 1981008
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @dateInt), 2, 6), 12)
```

To save you reading the comments, Gunther improved the performance by removing the substring operation in favour of subtraction:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR,@dateInt-1000000), 12)
```

Comment: substring won't accept numeric input; is it still performant if I convert everything first to string?

Comment: I changed the code to use INT. It's pretty quick on my system. I believe you will have to convert to a string since there's no INT->DATETIME conversion (least not in T-SQL as far as I know). This operation *should* have far less of an impact on performance than your IO and other relational operations.

Comment: I tried `convert(datetime,numdatecolumn-1000000,12)` but it gave wrong dates, guess I do need the string conversion, but I left out the substring by just subtracting 1e6. Thanks!

Comment: I had some problems with the query failing for an unknown reason; figured out it fails when year<2010, because then you have 5 characters eg `02/03/2004` --> `40302`. `Convert(...,12)` expects a 6-digit year. Fix is add a leading zero, eg with `RIGHT('0'+myvarchardate,6)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this if you are using C#.

```
string dateString = "1981008";
            DateTime dt;
            DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString.Remove(0,1), "yyMMdd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

In SQL (assuming it is MS SQL), try this:

```
convert(datetime,'981008',112)
```